# How to run Infinispan over ECS?

Tags: microservices, terraform, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb, infinispan

I want to run https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/infinispan-server/ over ECS as a Service. This container has the following ports open 7600 8080 8181 8888 9990 11211 11222 57600. I want to access all these ports by connecting ALB with the target groups. I know 11222 accessible from HTTP, but I don't know how to use other ports. Could someone please help me to understand how I can do that.
For example:
infinispan.mydomain.com -> 11222 (HTTP Infispan App)
infinispan9990.mydomain.com -> 9990
etc.....

How can I use all those ports in the target groups for health checks? If not, then how can I use infinispan and all its ports from another service.

I know there is an implementation over [EKS](https://infinispan.org/infinispan-operator/master/operator.html) but I want to use ECS. I tried it already but I didn't find any good article or way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Infinispan images (10+) have been designed to run with the infinispan-operator, so Infinispan on k8s or OKD is the first option.

Maybe you can find more info on how to adapt the image on ECS in the following pages:

- [Infinispan Image project](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-images)
- [ConfigGenerator for Infinispan](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-image-artifacts)